# HTML5 replacement for "center" for block divs with CSS?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to write an HTML-5 compliant document which passes the 
W3C validator : http://validator.w3.org/check .
The validator complains about each use of the <center> tag,
and suggests I should use CSS. 
Unfortunately, CSS does not seem to be capable of centering a BLOCK 
horizontally.  It can center text with 'text-align: center' attribute,
but attempts to center tables and images fail.
I have read the "CSS Centering Guide" at :
  http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html
but all its examples also fail to horizontally center a table or image
(at least on Firefox 36.0).
Can anyone please suggest how to center this table ?:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<title>CSS centering bug demo
</title>
<style type="text/css">
  .centered{ display: block;
             margin-left:auto;
             margin-right:auto;
             align: center;
             text-align: center;
             vertical-align: center;
             horizontal-align: center;
           }  
</style>
</head>
<body>  
  <div class="centered">
    <table width="60%">
      <tr>
        <td>Example Table</td>
        <td>which should be horizontally centered on the page.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `centered` class to the `table` if you want table to be in center.

```
<table width="60%" class="centered">
```

You also have some invalid properties in your css class as well. You just need to use the margin just like this

```
.centered {
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
}
```

So the bottom line is put the left and right margin as `auto` to the element which you want to be in center.

[Js Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/0od6j9r2/)

Comment: Thanks for the swift & informative response.  Your approach works OK for tables, but not for &lt;math&gt; or &lt;svg&gt; elements:

Comment: `svg` is an inline element, so in that case you also need to add `display:block` with it and then you can use this approach.

Comment: Thanks !  but why doesn't work to say in &lt;style&gt; section:
       math:  { display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
With only the above, math elements are not centered - I have to add:
      &lt;math class="centered" display="block"&gt; ... &lt;/math&gt;
for the math element to be centered.

Comment: `<style>` is used to define the `css` on the html. the content within this tag doesn't render on the page.

Comment: Yes, I know - I'm trying to define a &lt;style&gt; element that will cause &lt;math&gt; and &lt;svg&gt; elements to be centered, that I can specify as the elements' "class=" attribute,  but this doesn't seem to work with firefox's implementation of CSS.  Is this a firefox bug ?

Answer (score 1):

To reliably center a block element, do **all** of these:

1. Specify right and left margins and 
   — this is the key —
2. Specify **a definite width**, *e.g.*, pixels, **not** as percent (%).

```
div.center {
    margin-right: auto ;
    margin-left: auto ;
    width: 800px ;
    }
```

Specifying margins in one line, *e.g.*, `margin: auto ;` *usually* works; but, to stay on the safe side, specify each, *i.e.*, `margin-right: auto ; margin-left: auto ;`.

Whether or not this technique comports with the rules, I do not know — but my experience has been that it does work reliably.

Of course, it is annoying not to be able to specify `width:` as a percentage!

Answer (score 0):

- To center block-level elements with fixed width:

  ```css
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  ```

  ```css
  div {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div>I am block-level with fixed with</div>
  ```
- To center inline-level children:

  ```
  text-align: center;
  ```

  ```css
  div {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  span {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #00f;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div>
    <span>I am inline-level</span>
  </div>
  ```
- To center a block-level wrapper whose width adjusts to the content:

  ```
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  ```

  ```css
  div {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  p, span {
    border: 1px solid #00f;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div>
    I am a block-level centered wrapper
    <p>I am block-level child</p>
    <span>I am inline-level child</span>
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think CSS is simply broken / incorrect . It does not do what it says on the tin regarding centering.  I'm going to continue using the <center> element.

Comment: CSS is not broken. But you must understand how it works in order to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggested approaches work for <math> elements:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<title>CSS centering bug demo
</title>
<style type="text/css">
 .centered_block{ display: block;      /* this works ONLY for block elements with a fixed width  */
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
          }  
 .centered_text  {
            text-align: center;  /* this works ONLY for inline elements */
          }
 .centered_inline { text-align: center;  /* this works ONLY for inline block */
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;     
          }    
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <math class="centered_block">
    <mrow>
      <mfrac>
        <mrow><mi>a</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mi>b</mi></mrow>
      </mfrac>
    </mrow>
  </math>
  <math class="centered_text">
    <mrow>
      <mfrac>
        <mrow><mi>a</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mi>b</mi></mrow>
      </mfrac>
    </mrow>
  </math>
  <math class="centered_inline">
    <mrow>
      <mfrac>
        <mrow><mi>a</mi></mrow>
        <mrow><mi>b</mi></mrow>
      </mfrac>
    </mrow>
  </math>
</body>
</html>
```

All the math elments display left-justified. I guess it's back to <center> ... HTML5 & CSS seem poorly specified / not currently implemented correctly in modern browsers and seem incapable of centering these elements without <center> .